# sqlite malformed on a network drive

Tags: sqlite

I have been having an issue. I have some rather large databases (200 GB) that I store data in an sqlite database. I've been asked to move the files to my corporate network drive. However when I do they will work for a day or so and then I get an malformed error which means it's corrupted. I wasn't sure if anyone else has run into this problem or if there is something I can do to stop it from happening?

Comment: Unless your file share server guarantees the same semantic as a local filesystem in terms of atomicity, consistency, and locking,  do NOT do this.  As you've discovered, it appears yours does not.  If you need to do databases over a network, use a networked database system.  Sqlite is intended to run on a single host.

Comment: That being said, if it's for data tracking processes, etc., perhaps doing a _backup_ onto the network share daily would be sufficient?

Comment: I suspected it was something like this, thanks for the reponse